# 1.12.2 Forge and modern intelliJ IDEA not loading resources

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to get even the examplemod included with Forge MDK to work. no avail.

I added the Forge MDK project to IDEA and ran `genIntelliJRuns` and then clicked the **`runClient`**. The mcmod.info file isn't loaded.

I've tried adding
`sourceSets { main { output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir } }` to the bottom of the build.gradle.
Even after refreshing gradle, still no mcmod.info on **`runClient`**

I tried changing build and run to use IDE instead of Gradle, still no mcmod.info on **`runClient`**

[image]

This isn't just the mcmod.info file, its the whole resources.

This seems to be an issue ever since IDEA IntelliJ 14, and hasn't been fixed.

**Versions:**

- Forge 1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12
- Minecraft 1.12.2
- Gradle 4.9
- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2

Comment: Are there any errors in your build terminal after using `runClient`? I can say for sure that the 1.12 MDK works fine with IJ so there's something else causing this for you.

Comment: Can you post the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it, my build directory wasnt being overwritten. so even though I changed build.gradle, no changes happened, deleted the build directory and everything works fine.